# Union of Uncountably Infinite Sets

Tags: analysis, set-theory, notation

How does one notationally describe the set which is the union of uncountably many other sets.  For instance, for each x such that a < x < b, where a and b are real numbers, if there is assigned a set $N_x$,  how does one describe the union of all $N_x$ for all real x, a < x < b?

Comment: I would write it as $\cup_{x\in(a,b)}N_x$ or as $\cup_{a<x<b}N_x$. Or in `displaystyle': $\displaystyle{\cup_{x\in(a,b)}N_x}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any of the following is just fine:

$$\bigcup_{x\in(a,b)}N_x = \bigcup_{a<x<b}N_x = \bigcup\{N_x:x\in(a,b)\}=\bigcup\{N_x:a<x<b\}.$$

In general, if you have sets $S_\alpha$ indexed by elements of some set $A$, you can write $$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}S_\alpha = \bigcup\{S_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}.$$

If you have an *unindexed* collection $\mathscr{S}$ of sets, you can either write simply $\bigcup\mathscr{S}$ or use the sets themselves as indices: $$\bigcup_{S\in\mathscr{S}}S = \bigcup\{S:S\in\mathscr{S}\}.$$

Answer (score 4):

If $I$ is *any* index set, and $N_i$ is a set for $i\in I$ we write: $$\bigcup_{i\in I} N_i$$

Sometimes we write instead: $$\bigcup\{N_i\mid i\in I\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Usually something like this:

$$\bigcup_{a<x<b}N_x$$

In general, given any set $\Lambda$ (called "index set" in such a context) along with a collection of sets $A_x$ such that there is $A_x$ for every $x\in\Lambda$, one simply writes

$$\bigcup_{x\in\Lambda} A_x$$

To denote the union. So yo can also use

$$\bigcup_{x\in (a,b)}N_x$$

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as $$\bigcup_{a<x<b}{N_x}$$